# Magento 1.9.2 - How works Magento for take the value of the field VAT Number?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, vat

I'm studying the Magento process to pick the value from vat_id field and would like to ask you some questions to which I could not find an answer:

- In the function **public function getCustomerGroupIdBasedOnVatNumber($customerCountryCode, $vatValidationResult, $store = null)** That is present in data.php, where are defined $customerCountryCode and $vatValidationResult? Where is Their origin?
- How works Magento for take the value of the field "vat_id"?

Thanks for any help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCustomerGroupIdBasedOnVatNumber() This function is defined in Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php. And this function is called from below files, so you can check depending upon your need:

1) Mage/Sales/Model.Observer.php

2) Mage/Customer/Model/Observer.php

3)Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php

Hope this will help you.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. :) For $customerCountryCode and $vatValidationResult, where are defined???

Comment: $customerCountryCode  = $customerAddress->getCountryId()
$vatValidationResult = $customerHelper->checkVatNumber(
                    $customerAddress->getCountryId(),
                    $customerAddress->getVatId()
                );

Comment: Great! A last question please: What are the files where I can find these definitions?

Comment: in the above 3 files which I mentioned above.